# Life Time Api Authorization - OutSystems

Tags: api, authorization, outsystems

I try to get application information with the LifeTime Deployment API. According to this page, I have to create a service account to get a token.

https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/10/Reference/OutSystems_APIs/LifeTime_Deployment_API/REST_API_Authentication

But I am a trial user (free account for testing outsystems), so cannot create a service account.

Does Anyone know any other way to test the LifeTime Deployment API?

Sorry, I'm asking the same question at the outsystems official community.
https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/41274/life-time-api-authorization/#Post148428

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are out of luck. Using the trial cloud account you cannot do deployments as long as you have a single Development Environment and no other environments to deploy to. Therefore it doesn't even makes sense to have the LifeTime Deployment API available for this kind of subscription.